# How to maximize Access Application window using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` to open access db using code like this :

```
Access.Application AccApp = new Access.Application();
AccApp.Visible = true;
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(databasePathAndFileName, false, databasePassword);
```

The point is when access opens the window's size is small I need to maximize the access window after opening it .
Thanks

Comment: As a side note: Check if your customers really want this. I am sitting in front of a 32 inch screen at 2560x1440, and maximizing windows is pointless at that size (except for very rare circumstances).

Answer (score 3):

The VBA command for this is

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
```

which *should* be callable from C# interop as follows:

```
const int acCmdAppMaximize = 10;
AccApp.DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdAppMaximize);
```

Obviously, you can (and should) skip the redeclaration of the `acCmdAppMaximize` constant if it is already provided by the interop library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I got this `cannot convert from 'int' to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcCommand'`

Comment: I removed the declaration but I got `The name acCmdAppMaximize doesn't exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Heinzi who pointed me to the right direction , This worked for me :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application AccApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
AccApp.Visible = true;
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\\Settings.accdb", false, "017014A");
AccApp.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize);
```